# iphone is not able to support google map directions for more than 10 addresses

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-directions-api

Google mentioned that we can use 23 waypoints with one origin and one destination(total 25) in direction api. It works perfectly fine in javascript and java api. But when I tried to create direction link with 25 addresses and open it in **iphone**. Iphone's google maps app crashes. When I tried the same link in **android's** google maps app it worked fine. Iphone's app is also  working fine with 10 addresses, bus as soon as we open link with 11th address it crashes. I really need this feature. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**following is the link is google maps direction equivalent api I have created**

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/67+E+Evelyn+Ave,+Mountain+View,+CA+94041/68+E+Evelyn+Ave,+Mountain+View,+CA+94041/1630+S+Delaware+St,+San+Mateo,+CA+94402/525+El+Camino+Real,+Menlo+Park,+CA+94025/2120+Avy+Ave,+Menlo+Park,+CA+94025/1619+Hudson+St,+Redwood+City,+CA+94061/150+E+El+Camino+Real,+Sunnyvale,+CA+94087/690+Roberts+Rd,+Pacifica,+CA+94044/1750+Miramonte+Ave,+Mountain+View,+CA+94040/1050+Kiely+Blvd,+Santa+Clara,+CA+95051/329+Primrose+Rd,+Burlingame,+CA+94010/809+Laurel+St,+San+Carlos,+CA+94070/1600+Bryant+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94103/1600+Bryant+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94103/379+Geary+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94105/570+N+Shoreline+Blvd,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043/7373+Mission+St,+Daly+City,+CA+94014/639+S+Bernardo+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA+94087/298+W+McKinley+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA+94086/450+S+Abel+St,+Milpitas,+CA+95035/645+San+Antonio+Rd,+Mountain+View,+CA+94040/3567+Benton+St,+Santa+Clara,+CA+95051/6138+Bollinger+Rd,+San+Jose,+CA+95129/791+Middlefield+Rd,+Redwood+City,+CA+94063/67+E+Evelyn+Ave,+Mountain+View,+CA+94041

Comment: Have you tried using a [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) in directions mode? Note that your link is not an API call. Also the 23 waypoints limit refers to Directions API and cannot be applied to the link you posted in the question.

Comment: hi @xomena, I tried using Google Maps URLs in direction mode but it is taking only 9 waypoints and ignoring others.e.g https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Curr‌​ent+Location&destina‌​tion=1071+El+Camino+‌​Real,Redwood+City,CA‌​,94063&waypoints=37.‌​766623,-122.411231|3‌​7.390185,-122.065763‌​|37.372801,-122.0580‌​85|37.578088,-122.34‌​8845|37.503732,-122.‌​257458|37.469792,-12‌​2.223906|37.388168,-‌​121.857841|37.260318‌​,-121.874446|37.4313‌​47,-122.202023|37.46‌​9789,-122.223888|&tr‌​avelmode=driving&dir‌​_action=navigate     .  Please copy and paste link. 10 waypoints are given